# Using implemented members in the constructor (typescript)

Tags: class, typescript, abstract

I have found that when implementing a class, the members being implemented aren't available while inside the constructor. I can't tell if I'm implementing it wrong, or if I should really be taking a different approach.

```
abstract class Parent {
  abstract myVar: number;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.myVar) // Outputs undefined
  }

  f() {
    console.log(this.myVar) // outputs 5
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  myVar: number = 5;
}

let myChild = new Child;
myChild.f();
```

What can I do to access these implemented members in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class constructor will not be able to see the derived class's fields during its own execution.

You can use this pattern instead:

```
abstract class Parent {
  constructor(public myVar: number) {
    console.log(this.myVar) // Outputs 5
  }

  f() {
    console.log(this.myVar) // outputs 5
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super(5);
    }
}

let myChild = new Child;
myChild.f();
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    myVar: number = 5;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    myVar: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.myVar = 5;
    }
}
```

So you first call the super constructor, in which you're trying to access `myVar` which isn't yet assigned.

This is also clear from the compiled js:

```
var Parent = (function () {
    function Parent() {
        console.log(this.myVar);
    }
    Parent.prototype.f = function () {
        console.log(this.myVar);
    };
    return Parent;
}());
var Child = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Child, _super);
    function Child() {
        var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        _this.myVar = 5;
        return _this;
    }
    return Child;
}(Parent));
```

If you want to be able to access `myVar` in the `Parent` constructor you can do something like:

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract myVar: number;

    constructor() {
        this.init();
        console.log(this.myVar);
    }

    f() {
        console.log(this.myVar);
    }

    protected abstract init();
}

class Child extends Parent {
    myVar: number;

    protected init() {
        this.myVar = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a big fan of calling a virtual method from the constructor. The derived class might invoke a base class method, whose behavior will be undefined because the base class is still in a partially-initialized state.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh In most cases you're right, but sometimes it's hard to avoid. In any case, I used it here to illustrate the order of how things happen.